# Customise ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to replicate a layout in android. It looks like this[image]

The page is fairly simple except for the slider at the top. I initially thought that ViewPager would do the job but the app should allow the user to slider the numbers separately but the problem is I have no idea how to customise a ViewPager tablayout. I need it to show numbers with boxes like the picture above. Also I want to just change the data present in the page. I am going to have atleast 20 entries in the tablayout and I don't think having 20 fragments is the most efficient approach..

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: THIS IS WAHT YOU REQUIRED https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Answer (score 0):

> Simply add design library to gradle `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'`

```
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
            MainActivity.this));

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Now it work what you want.

Comment: I have looked at ViewPager but I have no idea how to change the tab looking things to numbers with square boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Tablayout setup with view pager.

Also use the following property in the xml of tablayout

```
  app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

Comment: the property allows the tab strip to be scrollable along with the pages under it also being scrollable :)